# Sequences in JAVA

Tags: java, string, sequence

I've been trying to generate this output :

> aaa aaa aab aOa baa aaa aab c

given this sequence:

> aaaab aOa baaab c

I'm really new to JAVA and I can't form the other sequences, just

> aaa aaa aab

I've been trying for a month so that's why I'm asking here, can someone help me please?

Here is my code:

```
public void generateSequence(String text, int n)
{
        text ="aaaab aOa baaab c";
        n=3; //i.e

        String[] words = text.split(" ");
        StringBuilder newGram = new StringBuilder();
        int p1 = 0;
        int p2 = n;
        String seq = "";
        int seqLength = seq.length();

        while (p1 < p2 && p2 <= seqLength) {
            newGram = newGram.append(seq.substring(p1, p2) + " ");
            p1++;
            p2++;

            if (p2 == seqLength) {
                System.out.println("End of 1st element");
                //Skip to the next elements in array and form sequences....
            }
        }
        System.out.println(newGram);
    }
```

Comment: You need to explain *a lot* more about how that input is supposed to generate that output. What are you passing in to your function that generates this output? Why do you set `seqLength` to 0 and only 0? Why do you do the same with `index`? You're also calling `substring` on the empty string `seq`.

Comment: Split your input on every space char. For each word, if (word.length<=3) print your word, else, for an integer index starting from 0 to your word length minus 3, print a substring of length 3 strating at index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String input = "aaaab aOa baaab c";
    final String[] sections = input.split(" ");
    final int length = 3;

    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final String section : sections) {
        for (int i = 0; i < section.length(); i++) {
            if (section.length() < length) {
                list.add(section);
                continue;
            }
            final int end = i + length;
            if (end > section.length()) {
                break;
            }
            final String result = section.substring(i, end);
            list.add(result);
        }
    }
    list.stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok user put some text now  n is the number of subsequences generated from the text, as you may know text are words and i save them into words array.

now if u  say pilot   for  n = 3

resulting array would be pil ilo lot

for n = 2

resulting array would be pi il lo ot

and so on

for  example  text = Java Rocks!

for n = 3

Jav ava Roc ock cks!

i want to generate n-gram according to some text as input and n for generating subsequences, could you put some code? thanks a lot.

Comment: Use the "edit" link to put this information in your question, don't use the "Answer" space (StackOverflow is not a forum, it's a Q&A site)

Comment: ok sorry im really new as i said i´ll check how to use this site :D